Internal Keyboard Acting Strange Locking me Out
Typing this on a phone. My 2020 MacBook Air’s internal keyboard is not working properly. The keys I, K, Z, 8, and , don’t work. What’s even stranger is that Function keys at the top (like the one that controls screen brightness) are going in as letters. I can tell through the forgot password thing that can be accessed without logging in, but resetting my password leads it to ask me to sign in with my ID, which also has an I.
And it’s not random either but sequential. F1 goes in as z. F2 goes in as x. F3 goes in as c. F4 goes in as v and so on, until I get to F8 which should go in as , doesn’t do anything. F9 goes in as “.”. F10 as /. Why is this? I can’t log into my account because my password has an i in it. What can I do?

If you plug in an external keyboard, does that keyboard behave the same?

The external keyboard I tried using didn’t work

@Tyler was that a wired keyboard?

Yeah it was wired

Did the wired keyboard you tried work correctly when plugged into a Mac other than yours? Alternatively, do you obtain the same result when plugging in a different wired keyboard?
